# get latitude/longitude from mapview on double click listener

Tags: android, google-maps

```
 Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
                GeoPoint loc = proj.fromPixels((int)ev.getX(), (int)ev.getY()); 
                String longitude = Double.toString(((double)loc.getLongitudeE6())/1000000);
                String latitude = Double.toString(((double)loc.getLatitudeE6())/1000000);
```

I am able to get latitude/longitude on dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
but i want it to be on double clicklistener

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                // get your LatLng from map
                return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }
        });

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }});
```

Comment: here touchview means mapview??